# Spring OAuth2 Client Credentials with UI

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, microservices, spring-oauth2

I'm in the process of breaking apart a monolith into microservices. The new microservices are being written with Spring using Spring Security and OAuth2. The monolith uses its own custom security that is not spring security, and for now the users will still be logging into the monolith using this homegrown security. The idea is that the new MS apps will have their own user base, and the monolith app itself will be a "user" of these Services. I've successfully set up an OAuth2 Auth Server to get this working and I'm able to log in with Client Credentials to access the REST APIs.

The problem is that the Microservices also include their own UIs which will need to be accessed both directly by admins (using the new Microservice users and a login page) and through the monolith (hopefully using client credentials so that the monolith users do not have to log in a second time). I have the first of these working, I can access the new UIs, I hit the login page on the OAuth server, and then I'm redirected back to the new UIs and authenticated & authorized.

My expectation from the  is that I can log in to the OAuth server with the client credentials behind the scenes and then use the auth token to have the front end users already authenticated on the front end.

My question is - what should I be looking at to implement to get the client credentials login to bypass the login page when coming in through the UI? Using Postman, I've gone to http://myauthapp/oauth/token with the credentials and gotten an access token. Then, I thought I could perhaps just GET the protected UI url (http://mymicroservice/ui) with the header "Authorization: Bearer " and I was still redirected to the login page.

On the UI app:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    protected static class ResourceConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails secure() {
            AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
            details.setId("secure/ui");
            details.setClientId("acme");
            details.setClientSecret("acmesecret");
            details.setAccessTokenUri("http://myoauthserver/secure/oauth/token");
            details.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://myoauthserver/secure/oauth/authorize");
            details.setScope(Arrays.asList("read", "write"));
            details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
            details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);


            return details;
        }


        @Bean
        public OAuth2RestTemplate secureRestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
            OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(secure(), clientContext);
            AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(
                    Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(
                            new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(),
                            new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(),
                            new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider())
                  );
                  template.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);

                  return template;
        }



    }
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


       @Autowired
        private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter;




        @Autowired
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
        }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.anonymous().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/ui").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(oauth2AuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }


    private LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint oauth2AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");
    }


}
```